# How to take a dump from mysql community server and restore in mysql enterprise edition?

Tags: phpmyadmin, mysql

please share the steps for the dump.

Syetem architecture - 64 bit'
os - rhel6

Answer (score 0):

Take dump by below command-

```
mysqldump -R -uroot -pyour_pass -A > backup.sql
```

Note: You can use various options here the above command will take all DB backup along with procedures. But you can take one or few databases etc.

Now go to target server and restore by below command-

```
mysql -uroot -pyour_pass < backup.sql
```